# Extracting the Server names from Dataframe and Grouping it in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe. In which i have the column called "Short Description".
I have filtered this column and taken in a list.

I have 2500 description in df. My descrpitions looks like below:

> - Summary: SD1: Low free LOG space in database saptempdb: 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Reso
> - Summary: SD1: Low free DATA space in database saptempdb: 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Res
> - Summary: Database FSPRO has used log space: 95.00% Date: 01/07/2017 Severity: Major ResourceId: svf
> - Unable to connect BD1 and BQ1 from GUI

I have done string split and saved in a list

```
#### Splitting the sentences ####
df['sentsplit'] = df["Short Description"].str.split(" ")
sent = df['sentsplit'].tolist()
```

> [[u'Summary:', u'SD1:', u'Low', u'free', u'LOG', u'space', u'in', u'database', u'saptempdb:', u'2.99%', u'Date:', u'01/01/2017', u'Severity:', u'Major', u'Reso'], [u'Summary:', u'SD1:', u'Low', u'free', u'DATA', u'space', u'in', u'database', u'saptempdb:', u'2.99%', u'Date:', u'01/01/2017', u'Severity:', u'Major', u'Res']

I need to extract my DB Names and group it.  For eg: In the first Description - saptempdb is a database, and second is also saptempdb. I need to group these statements.( BASICALLY NEED TO CLUSTER THE Description based on Same Database).

```
Summary: SD1: Low free LOG space in database saptempdb: 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Reso              SAPTEMPDB
Summary: SD1: Low free DATA space in database saptempdb: 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Res               SAPTEMPDB
Summary: Database FSPRO has used log space: 95.00% Date: 01/07/2017 Severity: Major ResourceId: svf              FSPRO
Unable to connect BD1 and BQ1 from GUI         Miscellaneous
```

I tried to exytract using pattern

```
import re
ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', sent )
print ip
```

Tried this as well. It doesn't follow the pattern always.

```
host_or_ip_re = re.compile(r'database (\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)|database (\w+)|Sys=([^, ]+),')
for line in log:
    m = host_or_ip_re.searc( line )
    if m:
        print m.groups()
```

Comment: are you refering to pandas dataframe? Regarding the question per se, have you tried something or are you asking for people to do the work for you? Hint: don't split the string and use [``re``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to extract the database name.

Comment: @ Francesco : Hi. Thanks for reply. To clarify,  I AM NOT ASKING PEOPLE TO WORK FOR ME  :) :).  I have tried few. But I am unsuccessful. I could be even wrong with my approach. Here I am pasting it in the question :)

Comment: If the message is always "database <name>" or "Database <name>" then regex should be able to get you the name. Can you please expand what you mean with "I need to group these statements" with an example related to the input data?

Comment: @ Francesco : Pls see the question. I have edied it with an example of grouped descripiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a variation of the provided input:

```
l = ['Summary: SD1: Low free LOG space in database saptempdb: 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Reso ',
     'Summary: Database FSPRO has used log space: 95.00% Date: 01/07/2017 Severity: Major ResourceId: svf ',
     'Summary: SD1: Low free DATA space in database saptempdb: 2.99% Date: 01/01/2017 Severity: Major Res ',
     'Unable to connect BD1 and BQ1 from GUI']
```

I create a dataframe and add an empty column

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame({'logs': l})
frame['names'] = ''
```

Then I create the regex to find the database name and use it to fill the `names` column:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[dD]atabase (\w+)')

for _, line in frame.iterrows():
    name = pattern.findall(line['logs'])
    if name:
        line['names'] = name[0]
    else:
        line['names'] = 'Miscellaneous'
```

Finally I sort the dataframe by the `names` column

```
frame.sort_values(by='names', inplace=True)
# frame.sort_values(by='names', inplace=False) returns a sorted copy of f
```

and get

```
                                                logs          names
1  Summary: Database FSPRO has used log space: 95...          FSPRO
3             Unable to connect BD1 and BQ1 from GUI  Miscellaneous
0  Summary: SD1: Low free LOG space in database s...      saptempdb
2  Summary: SD1: Low free DATA space in database ...      saptempdb
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your description is that you want to group all the description with the same Database Name.. Right ?

For this, if you have a predefined set of Database Name than you can create a list of database like db = ['saptempdb', 'FSPRO','BD1','BQ1'] and try to match these string from that list with the dataframe and than group it.

You are trying - `host_or_ip_re = re.compile(r'database (\d+:\d+:\d+:\d+)|database (\w+)|Sys=([^, ]+),')`

which will not work for "Unable to connect BD1 and BQ1 from GUI" as there is no **database** string in this statement.

Comment: That was helpful.. Thanks. How can I vote this answer as helpful ?